# how to check two dates between from-date and to-date

Tags: php, datetime

I have two dates `from-date` & `to-date`.

I have to compare them from existing  dates shown below, whether any of the day  fall between them or not using php?
i can do for single date checking ,but i am confuse for the two date checking.

Example: 
i have to check these dates:-> from=`15 March 2013`  & `15 April 2013`  between the following dates  whether any days falls in between these two date or not.

### following data from db table

```
 #       from date            to-date
-----------------------------------------
1     01 April 2013         30 April 2013   //here we will find as falling
2     01 May 2013           15 May 2013   
3     01 June 2013          20 June 2013
```

Currently,in my mind not even a single logic is coming to try. Please give me any logic or suggestions regarding this issue..

Comment: Do you want to check if a date is in between two dates?

Comment: Yes Exactly. I have mention the same in my question.  Its like i have to set my Amount Budget between two dates, if I have already set budget from newly type from-date & to-date. Then i have to show error message

Comment: check the Datetime class , did you ? there is a lot of methods one can use to compare dates.

Comment: @mpm  first time hearing about php Datetime class . i am checking it now....This is my first project in php

Comment: Are you getting the results from database? If yes then check this my `sql query`.

Comment: @DeadMan  Sorry! Please read my question once more.

Comment: Do you want to check if the _period_ 15 Match 2013 _to_ 15 April 2013 falls inbetween the three periods in the db table?

Comment: @Pärserk  Yes, exactly, now you know my actual doubt!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to compare dates is to convert them to a [unix timestamp](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)

Because the unix timestamp is an integer, you can simply use relational operators to compare them.

**Example**

```
// set some example data
$referenceDate = '01 April 2013';
$fromDate = '01 January 2013';
$toDate = '01 June 2013';

// convert dates to timestamps (strings to integers)
$referenceTimestamp = strtotime( $referenceDate );
$fromTimestamp = strtotime( $fromDate );
$toTimestamp = strtotime( $toDate );

// isBetween is Boolean TRUE if reference date is greater or equal fromDate and smaller or equal toDate
$isBetween = $referenceTimestamp >= $fromTimestamp and $referenceTimestamp <= $toTimestamp;
```

**EDIT 1**

To actually answer your question:

You have two ranges you need to test for overlap, this question has been answered here [What's the most efficient way to test two integer ranges for overlap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3269434/whats-the-most-efficient-way-to-test-two-integer-ranges-for-overlap)

```
// our two ranges overlap if the following conditions are met
$dateRangeOverlaps = $referenceFromTimestamp <= $toTimestamp and $fromTimestamp <= $referenceToTimestamp;
```

Comment: can you write comment, and explain it in little details, because am unable to understand your code. And why you are using  `$referenceDate = '01 April 2013';`?

Comment: you are very talented. You are answering me in very standard and in short cut way. I am unable to understand your code. Is it possible for you to make your answer simple?

Comment: Don't worry, you are most likely not less talented, it's just a matter of training and experience. I've added comments to each step, also read the answer I have linked.

Comment: But you are checking only one date `$referenceDate = '01 April 2013';` How can i check for my above posted date rows in between  the two dates? Please help

Comment: That's answered below EDIT1.

Comment: I tried to solve, but still have small problem. I posted question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15871992/php-unable-to-compare-two-dates-result?noredirect=1#comment22594984_15871992.  I think you can only help me

Answer (score -1):

Please try the code,

```
    $ourdate = strtotime('1 April 2013'); // Your date which is to be checked

    $from = strtotime('15 March 2013'); // From date
    $to = strtotime('15 April 2013'); // To date

    if ($ourdate >= $from && $ourdate <= $to)
    {
      echo "Date falls";
    }
    else
    {
    echo "No Date falls";
    }
```

If you need to check several dates, pass it as an array, like below...

```
   $i=0;
   $dates= array("11 April 2013","16 April 2013");
   foreach($dates as $ourdates)
   {
    $ourdate= strtotime($ourdates); //Your dates to be checked
    $from = strtotime('15 March 2013'); // From date
    $to = strtotime('15 April 2013'); // To date

          if ($ourdate >= $from && $ourdate <= $to)
              {
                 $i++;
              }
    }
    if($i>0)
    {
    echo "Date falls";
    }
    else
    {
    echo "No Date falls";
    }
```

Comment: i need to check between two date, you are checking only one date.  i have to check these dates:-> from=15 March 2013 & 15 April 2013 between the above shown date data.  If any of the day falls between these dates from my above shown data then i have to give error messsage

Comment: I edited the answer. If you are about to check for multiple dates, pass the dates as an array, like I did above..

Comment: i think you are not understanding my question doubt. Kindly read my question once again..