# PHP: unable to compare two dates result

Tags: php

I am comparing two date, `From_date` & `To_date` with My database table rows.

**Logic is:**  if users has already set budget between these 2 dates(dates received from textboxes),then return an error message `Budget already set for this from-date & to-date`.

i am converting my date into Unix Time-stamp for easier.

I refer this link before trying this: 
        1.  [how to check two dates between from-date and to-date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15803852/how-to-check-two-dates-between-from-date-and-to-date)
        2. 
            [What's the most efficient way to test two integer ranges for overlap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3269434/whats-the-most-efficient-way-to-test-two-integer-ranges-for-overlap?lq=1)

I tried the below code: but i am not getting result. 
It always shows me the wrong message **i.e** `Budget already set for this from-date & to-date`

```
 <?php  if (isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
             include '../../../include/connection.php'; 
             $frmdate= $_POST['frmdate'] ;
             $todate=$_POST['todate'] ; 
             $fromTimestamp = strtotime( $frmdate );
              $toTimestamp = strtotime( $todate ); 

     function  check_function($fromTimestamp,$toTimestamp)//function for checking the two dates which are rrecieved from the database table
           {
             $sid=$_SESSION['id'];
             $result12=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM budget where creater_id = '$sid'"); 
             while($test12 = mysql_fetch_array($result12))
                 {
                   $from_date = strtotime($test12['from_date']);//getting all the FROM-Dates_column
                   $to_date = strtotime($test12['to_date']);//getting all the TO-Dates_column

                    if((($fromTimestamp >= $from_date) && ($fromTimestamp <= $to_date)) || (($toTimestamp >= $from_date) && ($toTimestamp <= $to_date)))
                       {
                         return TRUE;
                         break;
                       }
                    return FALSE;
                  }
            }

           if(check_function($fromTimestamp,$toTimestamp))//Returns TRUE
              {
                  mysql_query("INSERT INTO `budget` (heads_id,amount,from_date,to_date,creater_id,created_date,updater_id,updated_date) VALUES ('$headsid','$amount','$frmdate','$todate',$uid,NOW(),$uid,NOW())");
              }
            else
              {
                 echo 'Budget already set for this from-date & to-date';   //
             }
        }  ?>
```

Comment: its because your `check_function` tend to return as false.

Comment: use `date_diff` for comparing two dates.

Comment: Try to print `print_r($test12)` and add return value on the end `check_function`. `return FALSE;` need to be on the function end not in `while`

Comment: no @Kaii, it has a `break;`

Comment: try echoing or var_dump what you are comparing  check_function -> if

Comment: not all paths of the function returns a value.

Comment: @UlfricStormcloak yes i already seen it :D

Comment: ok. But what if the result of the query is empty?

Comment: @YogeshSuthar I updated my question. Please read

Comment: seems you condition always falls to FALSE probably needed to reconstruct your condition in your if else statement mate.

Comment: @Kaii So accordning to you what should be the logic for comparing? I updated my question above,with few links. Please have a look

Comment: @Ashutosh yes but strip off thos extra `()` updated my ans..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one..

```
if(isset($to_date) && isset($from_date)){
    if((($fromTimestamp >= $from_date) && ($fromTimestamp <= $to_date)) || (($toTimestamp >= $from_date) && ($toTimestamp <= $to_date)))
    {
      $val = 'Y'; //return Y in meet this condition
    }
    else{
      $val = 'N'; // return N if meet this condition
    }
}
if($val == 'Y') //Returns TRUE
{
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `budget` (heads_id,amount,from_date,to_date,creater_id,created_date,updater_id,updated_date) VALUES ('$headsid','$amount','$frmdate','$todate',$uid,NOW(),$uid,NOW())");
}
else
{
echo 'Budget already set for this from-date & to-date';   //
}
```

Comment: still not all paths of the function returns a value.

Comment: @UlfricStormcloak oh yea great idea .. should update this to `isset()` thanks mate.

Comment: @Kaii Still the same error. Every time i submit date it shows the `Budget already set for this from-date & to-date`  . What's wrong!! please help

Comment: you said `Try to remove unnecessary () in your if conditions`  but () are not unnecessary,if i remove it is giving syntax error

Comment: @Ashutosh oh yea seen it thanks..check it now.. then update us

Comment: Sorry! Still same problem. Is my logic is correct? Every time its showing error `Budget already set for this from-date & to-date`

Comment: Sorry!! Still same problem. I updated my new code above. Please have a look.

Comment: hmm can u give values of your variables `$fromTimestamp,$toTimestamp,$from_date,$to_date` lets take it a try here

Answer (score 0):

> Did you try comparison with default mysql date format 2013/04/11
>   (Y/m/d) ?? If you are considering only date then you must store your
>   data in mysql database with Y/m/d format and also you can compare with
>   same ! it works best (y)

1) Store with MySQL Date format :

```
date("Y/m/d", strtotime($Date));
```

2) Comparing Dates

```
<?php  
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    include '../../../include/connection.php'; 
    $frmdate=  date("Y/m/d", strtotime($_POST['frmdate']));
    $todate= date("Y/m/d", strtotime($_POST['todate'])); 
     .. so on
}
?>
```

Comment: Still the same error. Every time i submit date it shows the `Budget already set for this from-date & to-date`  . What's wrong!! please help

Answer (score 0):

i just took a look at your code.

Your while loop tends to run only once. The return FALSE; statement is the last statement inside your while loop. Therefor if you query returns multiple results, which the loop seems to imply, you will always only fetch one result. After that run your function returns either true (when the first result is matched by the if statement) or false in any other case.

```
while($test12 = mysql_fetch_array($result12))
{
   $from_date = strtotime($test12['from_date']);//getting all the FROM-Dates_column
   $to_date = strtotime($test12['to_date']);//getting all the TO-Dates_column

   if((($fromTimestamp >= $from_date) && ($fromTimestamp <= $to_date)) || (($toTimestamp >= $from_date) && ($toTimestamp <= $to_date)))
   {
     return TRUE;
     break;
   }
   return FALSE;
}
```

On final note on the two statements

```
return TRUE;
break;
```

The break is not needed here, the return already breaks out of the while loop.

Hope this solves your problem!

Comment: Tried  but.    Still the same error. Every time i submit date it shows the `Budget already set for this from-date & to-date` . What's wrong!! please help`

Answer (score 0):

```
function  check_function($fromTimestamp,$toTimestamp)//function for checking the two dates which are rrecieved from the database table
 {
 $sid=$_SESSION['id'];
$result12=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM budget where creater_id = '$sid' and from_date >= $frmdate and to_date <= $todate")
if(mysql_num_rows($result12) > 0)
{
return true;
}
else
{
return false;
}
}


if(check_function($fromTimestamp,$toTimestamp)==TRUE)//Returns TRUE
              {
                  mysql_query("INSERT INTO `budget` (heads_id,amount,from_date,to_date,creater_id,created_date,updater_id,updated_date) VALUES ('$headsid','$amount','$frmdate','$todate',$uid,NOW(),$uid,NOW())");
              }
            else
              {
                 echo 'Budget already set for this from-date & to-date';   //
             }
```

Answer (score -1):

What the format from html form?
$frmdate= $_POST['frmdate'] ;
$todate=$_POST['todate'] ;

and what the format from your column table? ex: DATE, VARCHAR, TIMESTAMP, etc....