# TypeError: got multiple values for argument

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this code:

```
BOX_LENGTH = 100
turtle.speed(0)
fill = 0
for i in range(8):
    fill += 1
    if fill % 2 == 0:
        Horizontol_drawbox(BOX_LENGTH, fillBox = False)
    else:
        Horizontol_drawbox(BOX_LENGTH, fillBox = True)
        
    for i in range(8):
        fill += 1
        if fill % 2 == 0:
            Vertical_drawbox(BOX_LENGTH,fillBox = False)
        else:
            Vertical_drawbox(BOX_LENGTH,fillBox = True)
```

But I get an error that says:

```
    Horizontol_drawbox(BOX_LENGTH, fillBox = True)
TypeError: Horizontol_drawbox() got multiple values for argument 'fillBox'
```

What does this mean, and how can I fix the problem?

Comment: What is the declaration of the `Horizontol_drawbox` function? If it starts with `fillBox`, then that's the fault (assigned one time with positional argument, and a second time with keyword argument).

Comment: "I read the other threads that had to do with this error and it seems that my problem has an interesting distinct difference than all the posts I read so far" **Which** other questions (they are not "threads", as this is **not a discussion forum**)? I'm willing to bet that the differences are not actually interesting.

Comment: why did they break python by changing it all. Why didnt they call python3 cobra or something

Answer (score 483, accepted):

This happens when a keyword argument is specified that overwrites a positional argument. For example, let's imagine a function that draws a colored box. The function selects the color to be used and delegates the drawing of the box to another function, relaying all extra arguments.

```
def color_box(color, *args, **kwargs):
    painter.select_color(color)
    painter.draw_box(*args, **kwargs)
```

Then the call

```
color_box("blellow", color="green", height=20, width=30)
```

will fail because two values are assigned to `color`: `"blellow"` as positional and `"green"` as keyword. (`painter.draw_box` is supposed to accept the `height` and `width` arguments).

This is easy to see in the example, but of course if one mixes up the arguments at call, it may not be easy to debug:

```
# misplaced height and width
color_box(20, 30, color="green")
```

Here, `color` is assigned `20`, then `args=[30]` and `color` is again assigned `"green"`.

Comment: Interesting - when I hit this error, it was also about a `color` argument. The issue was a bit different - my `model_matrix` argument became keyword-only, and some legacy code had it passed as a positional argument. The new API was expecting `color`, and got a 4x4 matrix instead.

Comment: Hi, I don't get it for the second example. It also satisfies the condition: `When a keyword argument is specified that overwrites a positional argument`. But why the latter one can work? What's the rule when python assign the arguments. Thank you.

Comment: @Stallman: the second example I gave is also a non-working one. color=20 conflicts with color="green". The rule for assignment is given right after. More info: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments Particularly the 3rd of the 4 "invalid calls" examples.

Comment: I got this error when I did: `dict(**{'a': 1}, **{'a': 2})`. It works fine if we don't repeat the param names: `dict(**{'a': 1}, **{'b': 2})`.

Comment: @RoboRobok indeed, this is a "new way" (3.5) to get the error and is described in https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/#specification I suggest you add you own answer to the question, to make it easier for the next visitors to find your suggestion.

Answer (score 181):

I had the same problem that is really easy to make, but took me a while to see through.

I had copied the declaration to where I was using it and had left the `self` argument there, but it took me ages to realise that.

I had

```
self.my_method(self, a, b, c='123')
```

but it should have been

```
self.my_method(a, b, c='123')
```

Comment: Or replace first `self` with the class name. ;)

Comment: Great tip, my problem was very similar with invoking a super __init__ and accidentally had ` super().__init__(self, instance, *args, **kwargs)` instead of `super().__init__(instance, *args, **kwargs)`.

Comment: My problem was the opposite of this, was missing `self` in a class method!

Comment: My problem was _au contraire_ :-) I wasn't adding the 'self' parameter to a class method

Answer (score 114):

This also happens if you forget `self`declaration inside class methods.

Example:

```
class Example():
    def is_overlapping(x1, x2, y1, y2):
        # Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/12888920/940592
        return max(x1, y1) <= min(x2, y2)
```

**Fails** calling it like `self.is_overlapping(x1=2, x2=4, y1=3, y2=5)` 
with:

> {TypeError} is_overlapping() got multiple values for argument 'x1'

**WORKS**:

```
class Example():
    def is_overlapping(self, x1, x2, y1, y2):
        # Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/12888920/940592
        return max(x1, y1) <= min(x2, y2)
```

Comment: This comment helps me spot my problem: I forget to add a `self` argument inside the function declaration. i.e. what should be `def myFunction(self, a, b, c='123')` was written as `def myFunction(a, b, c='123')`. And because `b` takes a list and `c` takes a scalar, when missing self the arguments messed up and eventually the input of `b` goes to `c`, causing the "multiple arguments" error. I make this mistake because I tested this internal method outside the class and forget to add the `self` back in. Hope helpful for someone else!

Comment: @yuqli This is exactly how I get into this problem as well. ;) Nice to hear that this post helped you.

Comment: saved me quite some time as well :)

Comment: Also works after decorating the function with `@staticmethod` which may be a better approach when `self` is not inherently required.

Comment: Wow this is really non-obvious! I thought after over a decade of Python I knew what to look for to spot a "you forgot 'self' again!" error, but I was wrong... Thanks for this!

Answer (score 10):

This exception also will be raised whenever a function has been called with the combination of `keyword arguments` and `args`, `kwargs`

**Example:**

```py
def function(a, b, c, *args, **kwargs):
    print(f"a: {a}, b: {b}, c: {c}, args: {args}, kwargs: {kwargs}")

function(a=1, b=2, c=3, *(4,))
```

**And it'll raise:**

```py
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-1dcb84605fe5> in <module>
----> 1 function(a=1, b=2, c=3, *(4,))

TypeError: function() got multiple values for argument 'a'
```

> And Also it'll become more complicated, whenever you misuse it in the **inheritance**. so be careful we this stuff!

1- Calling a function with `keyword arguments` and `args`:

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self, a, b, *args, **kwargs):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
    
class B(A):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        a = 1
        b = 2
        super(B, self).__init__(a=a, b=b, *args, **kwargs)

B(3, c=2)
```

**Exception:**

```py
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-17e0c66a5a95> in <module>
     11         super(B, self).__init__(a=a, b=b, *args, **kwargs)
     12 
---> 13 B(3, c=2)

<ipython-input-5-17e0c66a5a95> in __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
      9         a = 1
     10         b = 2
---> 11         super(B, self).__init__(a=a, b=b, *args, **kwargs)
     12 
     13 B(3, c=2)

TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'a'
```

2- Calling a function with `keyword arguments` and `kwargs` which it contains keyword arguments too:

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self, a, b, *args, **kwargs):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
    
class B(A):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        a = 1
        b = 2
        super(B, self).__init__(a=a, b=b, *args, **kwargs)

B(**{'a': 2})
```

**Exception:**

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-c465f5581810> in <module>
     11         super(B, self).__init__(a=a, b=b, *args, **kwargs)
     12 
---> 13 B(**{'a': 2})

<ipython-input-7-c465f5581810> in __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
      9         a = 1
     10         b = 2
---> 11         super(B, self).__init__(a=a, b=b, *args, **kwargs)
     12 
     13 B(**{'a': 2})

TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for keyword argument 'a'
```

Comment: I don't understand the solution here. The error is explained but a solution is not offered?

Answer (score 7):

Simply put you can't do the following:

```
class C(object):
    def x(self, y, **kwargs):
        # Which y to use, kwargs or declaration? 
        pass

c = C()
y = "Arbitrary value"
kwargs["y"] = "Arbitrary value"
c.x(y, **kwargs) # FAILS
```

Because you pass the variable 'y' into the function twice: once as kwargs and once as function declaration.

Answer (score 7):

I was brought here for a reason not explicitly mentioned in the answers so far, so to save others the trouble:

The error also occurs if the function arguments have changed order - for the same reason as in the accepted answer: the positional arguments clash with the keyword arguments.

In my case it was because the argument order of the Pandas `set_axis` function changed between 0.20 and 0.22:

```
0.20: DataFrame.set_axis(axis, labels)
0.22: DataFrame.set_axis(labels, axis=0, inplace=None)
```

Using the commonly found examples for set_axis results in this confusing error, since when you call:

```
df.set_axis(['a', 'b', 'c'], axis=1)
```

prior to 0.22, `['a', 'b', 'c']` is assigned to axis because it's the first argument, and then the positional argument provides "multiple values".

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the same error in the following code:

```
re_path(r'^(?P<pos_id>\d+)/ctbl/(?P<ctbl_id>\d+)/set_commissioni/$', pos_forms.set_commissioni, name=url_views_pos_ctbl)
```

and the function:

```
def set_commissioni(pos_id=None, ctbl_id=None):
```

the error raised because i forgot request as first parameter of function

It would be:

```
def set_commissioni(request, pos_id=None, ctbl_id=None):
```

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error as I was using `@classmethod`.

If someone is getting this error while using `@classmethod` in the class, don't forget to pass the `cls` argument into the method:

```
class X:
  @classmethod
  def my_method(x):
    pass
```

The above code will raise cause the "TypeError: got multiple values for argument" error and you should pass `cls` like folloing:

```
class X:
  @classmethod
  def my_method(cls, x):
    pass
```

Comment: In my case, I was forgetting to put `self`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I wasn't explicitly passing the same argument twice. But the `django_rq` library function I was calling (`queue.enqueue`) was doing so internally. It seems it would automatically pass a value for any explicitly defined argument whether or not it was positional and THEN also add on any extra positional arguments.

So, I had to change my function definition to:

```
...
    ...
    queue = django_rq.get_queue('queue_name')
    job = queue.enqueue(
        function_to_call,
        arguments,
        keyword_arg=keyword_arg,
    )

...

# def function_to_call(arguments, keyword_arg=None): # OLD
def function_to_call(arguments, **kwargs): # NEW
```