# windrose: __init__() got multiple values for keyword argument

Tags: python, matplotlib, windrose

I know this is not a new issue, but everything I tried using the informations from the blogs I saw doesn't work for me. I tried to run this example for windrose:

```
from windrose import WindroseAxes
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import numpy as np
import imp

ws = np.random.random(500) * 6
wd = np.random.random(500) * 360

ax = WindroseAxes.from_ax()
ax.bar(wd, ws, normed=True, opening=0.8, edgecolor='white')
ax.set_legend()

ax = WindroseAxes.from_ax()
ax.contourf(wd, ws, bins=np.arange(0, 8, 1), cmap=cm.hot)
ax.set_legend()

ax.bar(wd, ws, normed=True, nsector=16)
table = ax._info['table']
wd_freq = np.sum(table, axis=0)

direction = ax._info['dir']
wd_freq = np.sum(table, axis=0)
plt.bar(np.arange(16), wd_freq, align='center')
```

But I only get this Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/Documents/the_windrose.py", line 31, in <module>
    plt.bar(np.arange(16), wd_freq, align='center')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2643, in bar
**kwargs)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/windrose/windrose.py", line 390, in bar
**kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for keyword argument 'width'
```

I don't understand the problem. What's wrong here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: got multiple values for argument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21764770/typeerror-got-multiple-values-for-argument)

Comment: The description of the answer in that post makes it sound like you have a variable named `width` somewhere that is conflicting with the optional `width` argument in the `plt.bar()` method call

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved! It's pretty simple if you look exactly what the code does. I made the mistake that I plotted the axis twice as you can see in the lines with `ax.bar(...)` and `ax.contourf(...)`. By running python tried every time to plot these two axis and got the error of multiple values.