# TypeError: scatter() got multiple values for argument 'c'

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, scipy, scatter-plot, hierarchical-clustering

I am trying to do hierarchy clustering on my MFCC array 'signal_mfcc' which is an ndarray with dimensions of (198, 12). 198 audio frames/observation and 12 coefficients/dimensions?

I am using a random threshold of '250' with 'distance' for the criterion as shown below:

```
    thresh = 250
    print(signal_mfcc.shape)
    clusters = hcluster.fclusterdata(signal_mfcc, thresh,    criterion="distance")
```

With the specified threshold, the output variable 'cluster' is a sequence [1 1 1 ... 1] with the length of 198 or (198,) which I assume points all the data to a single cluster.
Then, I am using pyplot to plot scatter() with the following code:

```
    # plotting
    print(*(signal_mfcc.T).shape)
    plt.scatter(*np.transpose(signal_mfcc), c=clusters)
    plt.axis("equal")
    title = "threshold: %f, number of clusters: %d" % (thresh) len(set(clusters)))
    plt.title(title)
    plt.show()
```

The output is:

```
    plt.scatter(*np.transpose(signal_mfcc), c=clusters)
    TypeError: scatter() got multiple values for argument 'c'
```

The scatter plot would not show. Any clues to what may went wrong? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From this [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21764770/typeerror-got-multiple-values-for-argument), you can see why you have this error.

Fom the [Scatter documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html), `c` is the 2nd optional argument, and the 4th argument total. This error means that your unpacking on `np.transpose(signal_mfcc)` returns more than 4 items. And as you define `c` later on, it is defined twice and it cannot choose which one is correct.

Example :

```
def temp(n, c=0):
    pass
temp(*[1, 2], c=1)
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
# TypeError: temp() got multiple values for argument 'c'
```

Comment: I tried using 'plt.scatter(x=np.arrange(198), y = signal_mfcc[:,0], c=clusters)' to try map the frames 'x' to its first coefficient 'y' and the scatter plot works! However, it seems like there will be alot of understanding to do with the clustering since it's not giving me the expected results. I really appreciate your help, thank you.