# TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'scoring' at Santander Customer Transaction database

Tags: python

I'm trying to run LOFOImportance at [Santander Customer Transaction database](https://www.kaggle.com/c/santander-customer-transaction-prediction) and I came across the following error:

```py
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from lofo.lofo_importance import LOFOImportance
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score

df_Train.sort_values("target", inplace=True)

cv = KFold(n_splits=4, shuffle=False, random_state=42)
target = "target"
features = [col for col in df_Train.columns if col != target]

lofo = LOFOImportance(df_Train, features, target, cv=cv, scoring = 'roc_auc')
importance_df = lofo.get_importance()
```

Has anyone had the same problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: got multiple values for argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21764770/typeerror-got-multiple-values-for-argument)

Answer (score 2):

If you look at `LOFOImportance.__init__`'s [signature](https://github.com/aerdem4/lofo-importance/blob/5d2d8857b244f31da7315c734e4409b52af09c5d/lofo/lofo_importance.py#L30) you will see that the second positional argument is `scoring`:

```
def __init__(self, dataset, scoring, model=None, fit_params=None, cv=4, n_jobs=None):
```

Hence your code

```
lofo = LOFOImportance(df_Train, features, target, cv=cv, scoring = 'roc_auc')
```

provides 2 difference values for `scoring` (as the error says): one as the positional argument `features` and the second as a keyword-argument, the string `roc_auc`.