# ‘TypeError: dict expected at most 1 arguments, got 4'

Tags: python

I tried to read many posts but was not able to fix the problem

I saw [TypeError: got multiple values for argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21764770/typeerror-got-multiple-values-for-argument)

but im too new to python to see how i can use that to fix the code.

```
rnd = Random()
post_data = dict()
categories = []
post_data[rnd.randint(1, 30000000)] = dict(
    categories==[
        12193,
        12191
    ],
    'country_code=US'
    'language=en'
    'limit=10'
)
```

Comment: provide complete error message

Comment: What do you expect as output in your dictionary? You're passing 4 arguments to the `dict`, which is incorrect.

Comment: This is not the correct way to use `dict()` instead use the `{}` to define a dictionary and insert values in it.

Comment: Note that `==` is a comparison giving `False` here as `categories` is an empty list and is not equal to the provided list with 2 elements. Furthermore, the second parameter is 1 string broken over 3 lines of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here why you are passing four arguments to `dict`

```
dict(
    categories==[
        12193,
        12191
    ],
    'country_code=US'
    'language=en'
    'limit=10'
)
```

and `==` is logical comparison, it is simply `dict(key=value,key1=value1)` dont forget the comma `,` too. You should do like this

```
dict(
     categories=[
         12193,
         12191
      ],
      country_code='US',
      language='en',
      limit='10',
  )
```

Output:

> {'categories': [12193, 12191],  'country_code': 'US',  'language':
>   'en',  'limit': '10'}

Comment: No, you cannot use the empty list `categories` as a dictionary key and the output you show is only obtained if you set `categories='categories'`.

Comment: @JoachimWagner `categories` here is not a list key can be never a list. dictionary keys can be only immutable data structures here `categories` will be key of  type *string* and  having value `[]` try this on shell and see `dict(categories=[ ])`

Comment: @JoachimWagner No you are wrong about putting quotes here why dont you give a try in shell before commenting I ll close the answer if it fails

Comment: Apologies, I wasn't expecting that Python treats stuff inside `dict()` special. Really bad then that key words are still not allowed, e.g. `dict(for='10')` doesn't work.

Comment: @JoachimWagner actually it is same like `**kwargs` works it is `dict` let us not confuse the interpertor with keywords here ;)

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense and explains why special words like `for` are not allowed as keys in this syntax. Best to recommend to beginners to use `{}`.

Comment: @JoachimWagner `for` is allowed in dict but as  an expression for dictionary comprehension try this `{ k:v for k,v in [("a",2)]}`

Comment: I get an exception when I try `dict(for='10')` and this makes sense with your explanation that this is not special syntax but a normal named parameter call of a function. See also my `one='appel'` edit in @Abhishek-Saini's answer. Of course I know I can write `{'for':'10'}` instead.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200693/discussion-between-joachim-wagner-and-yugandhar-chaudhari).

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems in your `dict()` call.

(1) Are you trying to use the empty dictionary `categories` as a key, are you comparing the empty dictionary to the provided list, giving `False` with the initialisation shown in the example, or do you want to have a key-value pair `('categories', [12193, 12191])`? If the latter, do you want the list to be the list `categories` so that when you do `categories.append(123)` the value under the key `categories` also changes?

(2) Your second argument to `dict()` is the string 'country_code=USlanguage=enlimit=10', broken in the code over 3 lines. You probably want 3 key-value pairs `('country_code', 'US')`, `('language', 'en')`, and `('limit', '10')` or `('limit', 10)`.

(3) You seem to be mixing syntax for a `dict()` call with syntax for the `{...}` construction. The former expects key-value pairs in the named parameter syntax, while the later uses alternating colons and commas to separate keys and values.