# TypeError: send_login_mail() got multiple values for argument 'email'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, celery

I am learning Celery+Reddis and trying to send email through Celery. I have created a task in which I have encapsulated my send email logic. I am calling the `send_login_mail` function and passing the keyword arguments using `.delay()`.

```
#views.py
class SignUpOTP(APIView):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    def post(self, request):
        request_email = request.data.get("email",)
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(email__iexact = request_email)
            return Response({"status": "User is already registered."}, status=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)
        except:
            if request_email:
                    send_login_mail.delay(email=request_email, subject="[OTP] New Login for Connect App")
                    return Response({'status':'OTP sent successfully.'},status = status.HTTP_200_OK)
            else:
                return Response({"status":"Please enter an email id"},status = status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

```
#tasks.py
@shared_task(bind=True)
def send_login_mail(email=None, subject="[OTP] New Login for Connect App"):

    print("Wowowofdsofsdojsdjdofdffdojodjodfdfjdoofdods\nsdfjdsfjdsofjdsojdsdsosdoosdjfosdsdfodf")
    OTP.objects.filter(otp_email__iexact = email).delete()

    otp = random.randint(100000,999999)

    msg = EmailMessage(subject, f'<div style="font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;min-width:1000px;overflow:auto;line-height:2"><div style="margin:50px auto;width:70%;padding:20px 0"><div style="border-bottom:1px solid #eee"><a href="" style="font-size:2em;color: #FFD243;text-decoration:none;font-weight:600">Connect</a></div><p style="font-size:1.2em">Greetings,</p><p style="font-size:1.2em"> Thank you for creating an account on Connect. You can count on us for quality, service, and selection. Now, we would not like to hold you up, so use the following OTP to complete your Sign Up procedures and order away.<br><b style="text-align: center;display: block;">Note: OTP is only valid for 5 minutes.</b></p><h2 style="font-size: 1.9em;background: #FFD243;margin: 0 auto;width: max-content;padding: 0 15px;color: #fff;border-radius: 4px;">{otp}</h2><p style="font-size:1.2em;">Regards,<br/>Team Connect</p><hr style="border:none;border-top:1px solid #eee" /><div style="float:right;padding:8px 0;color:#aaa;font-size:1.2em;line-height:1;font-weight:500"><p>Connect</p><p>Boys Hostel, Near Girl Hostel AKGEC</p><p>Ghaziabad</p></div></div></div>', 'swaad.info.contact@gmail.com', (email,))
    msg.content_subtype = "html"
    msg.send()

    time_created = int(time.time())
    OTP.objects.create(otp=otp, otp_email = email, time_created = time_created)
    
    return Response({"OTP has been successfully sent to your email."})
```

Am I using .delay() wrong? I have tried using .apply_async() but still couldn't make it work.`p`

Comment: where you defined email: `request_email = request.data.get("email",)` try removing the `,`

Comment: @Lewis That is a python thing. 
"To create a tuple with only one item, you have add a comma after the item, unless Python will not recognize the variable as a tuple." - Source: W3Schools

Answer (score 0):

```
send_login_mail.delay(request_email) or
send_login_mail.delay(request_email, "[OTP] New Login for Connect App")
```

might work without issue.

Also there is no point of keep None default argument email, make it a positional argument instead.

Celery might got two argument named email.

Refer the following link:
[TypeError: got multiple values for argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21764770/typeerror-got-multiple-values-for-argument)

Comment: Thank You it worked... I don't know why keyword arguments failed. Also, I think I needed to restart the celery worker as it didn't respond to the changes when I changed it to positional arguments. Thank You for your help! Also, Happy New Year!