# Select * from table where desired period does not overlap with existing periods

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with records and a period of time for each record, like reservations for instance. So my records look like this:

```
Table-reservations
id  room    datefrom        dateto
1   'one'   '2015-09-07'    '2015-09-12'
2   'two'   '2015-08-11'    '2015-09-02'
3   'three' '2015-06-11'    '2015-06-14'
4   'two'   '2015-07-30'    '2015-08-10'
5   'four'  '2015-06-01'    '2015-06-23'
6   'one'   '2015-03-21'    '2015-03-25'
...
n   'nth'   '2015-06-01'    '2015-07-03'
```

Also there is a table with rooms containing an ID, a roomnumber and a roomtype, like this:

```
Table-rooms
idrooms   room      roomtype
1         'one'     'simple'
2         'two'     'simple'
3         'three'   'double'
...
nx        'nth'     'simple'
```

As you can see some rooms appear multiple times, but with different periods, because they are booked on various periods.
What I need to obtain through SQL is a list of rooms that are available in a given period of time.

So something like(pseudocode):

```
Select room from table where there is no reservation on that room between 2015-08-13 and 2015-08-26
```

How can I do this?

So I will have a fromdate and a todate and I will have to use them in a query.

Can any of you guys give me some pointers please?

Right now I use the following sql to obtain a list of rooms that are available NOW

```
select * from rooms
 where idrooms not in
 (
 select idroom from rezervations where
 ((date(now())<=dateto and date(now())>=datefrom)or(date(now())<=dateto and date(now())<=datefrom))
 )
 order by room
```

Comment: Is there a separate table of all of your rooms?  or do we have to assume this "reservations" table is the only one that exists?

Comment: There is one, you are right. Consider something like: table rooms with `(integer:idroom, varchar():room, varchar():type)`

Comment: update your question to include this as it is vital to getting a full answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to check that records don't exist where 'date from' is less than or equal to the end date in your range and 'date to' is greater than or equal to the start date in your range.

```
select t1.room
from reservations t1
where not exists (
  select *
  from reservations t2
  where t2.room = t1.room
  and t2.datefrom <= '2015-08-26'
  and t2.dateto >= '2015-08-13'
)
group by room
```

You can try it out here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cbd59/5

I'm new to the site, so it won't let me post a comment, but I think the problem on the first answer is that the operators should be reversed.

As mentioned in a previous comment, this is only good if all of the rooms have a reservation record. If not, better to select from your rooms table like this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0b96e/1

```
select room
from rooms
where not exists (
  select *
  from reservations
  where rooms.room = reservations.room
  and reservations.datefrom <= '2015-08-26'
  and reservations.dateto >= '2015-08-13'
)
```

Comment: For your second query here is my Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/39c45/1 and it's not working properly. Explanations can be found in the query part of the Fiddle

Comment: You need to reverse your range dates, so that datefrom <= 'range end' and dateto >= 'range start'.

Comment: #Kendall thanks, yours is the winner so far. I will do some more tests to make sure, but with my test case it seems to work ok.

Comment: I hope it helps. I'll monitor the thread in case the query needs modification.

Answer (score 2):

This might be easier to understand.

Assuming you have another table for rooms.

```
SELECT * 
FROM rooms 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT id 
                  FROM reservations 
                  WHERE reservations.room = rooms.id 
                    AND datefrom >= '2015-08-13' 
                    AND dateto <= '2015-08-26')
```

Comment: This looks perfect. Thanks

Comment: Wait. it's not that perfect... I have bad cases. I will ellaborate in next comment

Comment: a bad dateto in the first inserted record. The month should be 09 instead of 08. Please fix it before testing it

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.room
FROM yourTable a
WHERE a.room NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT( b.room )
    FROM yourTable b
    WHERE datefrom >= '2015-08-13'
        OR dateto <= '2015-08-26'
);
```

It should work to the best of my guesses. If it doesn't; could you please provide a sqlfiddle to check the data on?

Comment: `and` instead of `or`?

Comment: this is good if there aren't rooms that have never been booked before.

Comment: @vkp I don't think so. There might be rooms which had been booked for longer than that.

Comment: @JosephDuty Yes, I have considered that possibility; but can't do anything with the data OP provided.

Answer (score 0):

Using this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3269434/whats-the-most-efficient-way-to-test-two-integer-ranges-for-overlap)

Consider

> range1 : r11 r12   [inputfromDate    inputToDate]
> range2 : r21 r22   [datefromColumn  datetoColumn]
>
> IF r11 <= r22 && r21 <= r12, then the ranges are overlapping.

There are 6 possible case, where two ranges can overlap. But the above two condition itself handles all the 6 possibilities.

If the above condition matches then that means, the dates are overlapping. So I have used `not in` to get the remaining entries.

```
select * from <table-name> where id not in (
   select id from <table-name> where 
   :inputfromDate <= datetoColumn and datefromColumn <= :inputToDate
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try this :

```
select * from rooms
    where room not in(
    select room from reservations
    where '2015-09-16' >= datefrom  
    and '2015-09-16' <=dateto 
    and '2015-09-21' >= dateto
)
```

Goodluck!

Comment: Same problem here... periods are overlapping, even if just partially but they are overlapping. Please check this fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7f7ed/1

Comment: @user1137313 I updated the answer. please take a look.