# Calculate intersection of continuous integer sequences?

Tags: javascript, numerical-methods

In JavaScript what is the proper way to calculate intersection of continuous integer sequences?

For example `A = (1...10)` and `B = (7...20)` and `C = (3..5)` — as the result i want to know that A intersects B, but B do not intersects C.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your variables A/B/C are arrays ?

Comment: No, actually, they might just numbers.

Comment: if they are sorted you can quickly compare first/last. if you use something like Math.max.apply(null, rng1), you can quickly find the bounds like a sorted would allow. at any rate, you should not need to loop, that's for suckers on this kind of a problem.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Or our we going to answer your homework for you?

Comment: @Adam Buchanan Smith good question ! :D

Comment: Actually no. I have only border values.

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith i'm out of ideas for now, so decided to ask a community for a tip. (Only thing i came up with is to substract border values)

Comment: You could probably try [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#intersection). Also, it would help to see your full input and your full expected output.

Comment: @walkthroughthecode so what have you tried?

Comment: i ended up with nested .map() to compare each set (represented as object with keys start and end) — but that feels just wrong

Comment: I think you mean "contiguous" rather than "continuous".

Comment: @shawnt00 no, i meant that this is just sequences like 1,2,3,4.. without holes inbetween.

Comment: @walkthroughthecode It's a relatively small distinction in math terminology but we won't worry about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `A`, `B` & `C` are arrays then you can assemble an object with your bounding values like so:

```
bounds_a = {
    start: Math.min.apply(null, A),
    end: Math.max.apply(null, A),

}
```

You could even make a class for this to help:

```
var Bounds = function(src){
    this.min = Math.min.apply(null, src)
    this.max = Math.max.apply(null, src)
    this.size = Math.abs(max - min + 1) //+1 since we're dealing with integers and need to account for the lowest value
}

Bounds.prototype.intersects = function(target){
    rangeMin = Math.min(this.min, target.min)
    rangeMax = Math.max(this.max, target.max)

    range = Math.abs(rangeMax - rangeMin)
    width = this.size + target.size

    return range < width
}
```

A better explanation of the overlap logic can be found here - [What's the most efficient way to test two integer ranges for overlap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3269434/whats-the-most-efficient-way-to-test-two-integer-ranges-for-overlap)

Testing this:

```
var A = <array 1...10>
var B = <array 7...20>
var C = <array 3...5>

var a = new Bounds(A) //min: 1, max: 10, size: 10
var b = new Bounds(B) //min: 7, max: 20, size: 14
var c = new Bounds(C) //min: 3, max: 5, size: 3

a.intersects(b) //true
b.intersects(c) //false
a.intersects(c) //true
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var intersect = function(a, b) {
    // Assume a & b are sorted

  var c = []

  for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        for(var j = 0; j < b.length; j++) {
        if(a[i] == b[j]) {
          c.push(a[i]);
        }
      }
    }
    return c;
  }

A = []
B = []

A.push(1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 7)
B.push(2,4,8,10,7,5,1)
A.sort()
B.sort()

alert(intersect(A,B))
```

Comment: Actually i was asking about a signature like so `{ start: 3, end: 10 }`, so this is not quite a fit.

Answer (score 0):

Best I can tell you only want to know if they do intersect.

```
is_intersecting = (minA <= maxB && maxA >= minB);
```

Based on a comment, you could substitute `a.start` for `minA`, `a.end` for `maxA`, and do on. Possibly better to just wrap this up in a function.

Answer (score 0):

Use a class and a method which returns a new range object if there is one result. This solution works for any floats or gaps.

```js
function Range(lower, upper) {
    this.lower = lower;
    this.upper = upper;
}

Range.prototype.intersection = function (r) {
    var i = new Range(Math.max(this.lower, r.lower), Math.min(this.upper, r.upper));
    return i.lower <= i.upper ? i : undefined;
};

var a = new Range(1, 10), //   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
    b = new Range(7, 20), //               7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
    c = new Range(3, 5),  //       3 4 5
    d = new Range(0, 1);  // 0 1

function print(o) {
    document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(o, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
}

print(a.intersection(b)); // { lower: 7, upper: 10 }
print(a.intersection(c)); // { lower: 3, upper: 5 }
print(a.intersection(d)); // { lower: 1, upper: 1 }
print(b.intersection(c)); // undefined
print(b.intersection(d)); // undefined
print(c.intersection(d)); // undefined
```