# Detect collision between two elements

Tags: javascript

I want to detect a collision between two divs and I've tried to do that using the `offsetLeft` and `offsetTop` of each one of the divs and by using `getBoundingClientRect()`. But none of these work.

**Is there a way I can get the exact coordinates in which these two elements touch?**

```js
const bigDiv = document.querySelector(".big")
const blue = document.querySelector(".blue")
const startBtn = document.querySelector("button")
const red = document.querySelector(".red")
const bigDivDimensions = bigDiv.getBoundingClientRect();
let speed = 5;
//let counter = 0;


let bigDivLeft = bigDivDimensions.left;

startGame();

function random() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (bigDivDimensions.width - 40));
}

function startGame() {
  //let randomSnake = Math.floor(Math.random()*(bigDivDimensions.width-40));
  //let randomApple = Math.ceil(Math.random()*(bigDivDimensions.width -40));
  blue.style.left = random() + "px"
  blue.style.top = random() + "px"
  red.style.left = random() + "px"
  red.style.top = random() + "px"
}

function move(e) {
  let blueX = blue.offsetLeft;
  let blueY = blue.offsetTop;
  let key = e.keyCode;

  if (key !== 37 && key !== 38 && key !== 39 && key !== 40) {
    return
  } else if (key === 37 && blueX > 3) {
    blueX -= speed;
  } else if (key === 38 && blueY > 3) {
    blueY -= speed;
  } else if (key === 39 && blueX < (bigDivDimensions.width - 25)) {
    blueX += speed;
  } else if (key === 40 && blueY < (bigDivDimensions.height - 23)) {
    blueY += speed;
  }

  blue.style.left = blueX + "px";
  blue.style.top = blueY + "px";
  colision(blueX, blueY)
}

function colision(blueX, blueY) {
  /* let redX = red.offsetLeft;
     let redY = red.offsetTop; 
     if(redY === blueY || redX == blueX){console.log("hit")}  */

  let redRect = red.getBoundingClientRect();
  let blueRect = blue.getBoundingClientRect();

  if ((redRect.top < blueRect.bottom) || (redRect.bottom < blueRect.top) || (redRect.right > blueRect.left) || (redRect.left < blueRect.right)) {
    console.log("hit")
  }
}

startBtn.addEventListener("click", startGame)
document.addEventListener("keydown", move)
```

```css
.big {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  outline: 1px solid red;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

.blue {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: blue;
  position: absolute;
}

.red {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<button type="button">Start Game</button>
<div class="big">
  <div class="blue"></div>
  <div class="red"></div>
</div>
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/mullerz/pen/vYNjXWQ)

Comment: [Check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12066870/how-to-check-if-an-element-is-overlapping-other-elements)

Comment: and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Techniques/2D_collision_detection)

Answer (score 0):

Two rectangles do collide when their

> horizontal side and vertical side

**overlap**.

Consider the following answer: [Checking for range overlap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40568618/3589620)

```
// l1 (line 1) --> [x1, x2]
// l2 (line 2) --> [x1, x2]
function checkOverlap(l1, l2) {
  return ((l1[1] - l2[0]) > 0 && (l2[1] - l1[0]) > 0) ? true : false;
}
```

Check collision with range overlap for *the x-side* and *y-side*:

```
// Rectangle a --> [[x1, x2], [y1, y2]]
// Rectangle b --> [[x1, x2], [y1, y2]]
function collide(a, b) {
  return (checkOverlap(a[0], b[0]) && checkOverlap(a[1], b[1]));
}
```

---

### Spoiler

**SVG-Example**

```js
var svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
var width = 200;
var height = 200;
svg.setAttribute("width", width);
svg.setAttribute("height", height);
document.body.appendChild(svg);

function createRect(svg, width, height, x, y, style, id) {
  var rect = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "rect");
  rect.setAttribute("width", width);
  rect.setAttribute("height", height);
  rect.setAttribute("x", x);
  rect.setAttribute("y", y);
  rect.setAttribute("style", style);
  rect.setAttribute("id", id);
  svg.appendChild(rect);
}

function createSquare(svg, side, x, y, style, id) {
  createRect(svg, side, side, x, y, style, id);
}

function getRandomNumber(a, b) {
  return Math.round(Math.random() * (b - a)) + a;
}

function createRandomSquare(svg, xRange, yRange, side, style, id) {
  var x = getRandomNumber(xRange[0], xRange[1]);
  var y = getRandomNumber(yRange[0], yRange[1]);
  createSquare(svg, side, x, y, style, id);
  return [
    [x, x + side],
    [y, y + side]
  ];
}

function checkOverlap(l1, l2) {
  return ((l1[1] - l2[0]) > 0 && (l2[1] - l1[0]) > 0) ? true : false;
}

// [[x1, x2], [y1, y2]]
function collide(a, b) {
  return (checkOverlap(a[0], b[0]) && checkOverlap(a[1], b[1]));
}

function getCoordinates(arr) {
  return {
    "top-left": [arr[0][0], arr[1][0]],
    "top-right": [arr[0][1], arr[1][0]],
    "bottom-left": [arr[0][1], arr[1][1]],
    "bottom-right": [arr[0][0], arr[1][1]]
  }
}

function run() {
  var bs = document.getElementById("blueSquare");
  var rs = document.getElementById("redSquare");
  var output = document.getElementById("output");
  output.innerHTML = "";
  if (bs !== null && rs !== null) {
    var parent = bs.parentNode;
    parent.removeChild(bs);
    parent.removeChild(rs);
  }

  var side = 30;
  var blueSquare = createRandomSquare(svg, [0, (width - side)], [0, (height - side)], side, "fill:blue", "blueSquare");
  var redSquare = createRandomSquare(svg, [0, (width - side)], [0, (height - side)], side, "fill:red", "redSquare");
  var output1 = "Collision? " + collide(blueSquare, redSquare);
  var output2 = "Blue square: " +
    JSON.stringify(getCoordinates(blueSquare));
  var output3 = "Red square: " + JSON.stringify(getCoordinates(redSquare));
  output.innerHTML = output1 + "<br>" + output2 + "<br>" + output3 + "<br>";
}

var button = document.createElement("button");
button.setAttribute("id", "button");
button.textContent = "Run";
button.addEventListener("click", run);
document.body.appendChild(button);
```

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```