# Whether two number ranges with possible infinities intersect

Tags: python, range, comparison

A question similar to [What's the most efficient way to test two integer ranges for overlap?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3269434/856090) but a little more advanced:

Let we are given two inclusive integer number ranges [x1:x2] and [y1:y2], where x1 ≤ x2 and y1 ≤ y2.

x1 and/or y1 can be an integer or minus infinity (represented as `None` Python object), x2 and/or y2 can be an integer or plus infinity (represented as `None` Python object).

What is the best way to test whether there is any overlap of the two ranges?

I am sure I can write an algorithm, but maybe you will find a shorter Python code for me?

(In fact, I deal not with integers but with version strings like "3.7". But I think I will have no trouble moving from integers to version strings by myself.)

Comment: One way is to create an object with overridden comparison operators wrapping an integer (or a version number) with possible `None` and then using the same formula as in https://stackoverflow.com/q/3269434/856090

Comment: If the step-size is always `1`, isn't this a mere set of inequations, chaining some conditions like `(x1 <= y1 and x2 >= y1) or (...)`?

Comment: If you're comparing version strings, consider using [existing tools for that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11887762/how-do-i-compare-version-numbers-in-python).

Comment: @user2357112 I already use `deb_pkg_tools.version.Version` to compare Debian (currently I support only Debian and derivatives) version strings

Comment: There's already a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3269434/whats-the-most-efficient-way-to-test-two-integer-ranges-for-overlap

Comment: @AndrejKesely I have already referred to this question in my question. The distinction of my question is that in my variant of the questions values can be infinite

Comment: @porton: Yes, but an easy variant of that solution gives a solution for this problem: just use `(x1 is None or y2 is None or x1 <= y2) and (y1 is None or x2 is None or y1 <= x2)`

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work, just checking the different relations that can exist between `x1, x2, y1, y2`. This can probably be written in shorter form but this code emphasize the different cases.

```
def checkIntersection(x1, x2, y1, y2):
    if x1 is not None:
        if y1 is not None:
            if x1 <= y1 and (x2 is None or x2 > y1):
                return True
            elif y1 <= x1 and (y2 is none or y2 > x1):
                return True
            else:
                return False
    else:
        if y1 is None:
            return True
        else:
            if x2 is None or x2 > y1:
                return True
            return False
```

And a more elegant solution -

```
import numpy as np

def checkIntersection(x1, x2, y1, y2):
    x1 = x1 if x1 is not None else -np.inf
    y1 = y1 if y1 is not None else -np.inf
    x2 = x2 if x2 is not None else np.inf
    y2 = y2 if y2 is not None else np.inf
    return (x1 <= y1 and x2 >= y1) or (y1 <= x1 and y2 >= x1)
```

Comment: Your solution is elegant, but sadly it won't work with my real requirement, comparing version number strings

Comment: In your second example, I think it's enough to check that `x1 <= y2 and y1 <= x2`