# check validation between to dates and time

Tags: php, mysql

I have this if statement

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $(document).on('submit', '#rentform', function () {
            var data = $(this).serialize()

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'newrent.php',
                data: data,
                success:(
                    function (data){$(".result").html(data)}

                )
            });
            return false;
        });
    } )

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#rent').change(function(){
            var x =($('#rent option:selected').data('sireal'))
            $('#itemsn').val(x);
        });
    } )
</script>


<form method="post" id="rentform" action="" novalidate="novalidate">
    <label for="item">REnter Name</label>
    <select name="rnt_name" id="name_rent">
        <option selected disabled>SELECT Renter Name</option>
        <?php foreach ($nameq as $res) : ?>
            <option value="<?= $res['user_name']?>"><?= $res['user_name'] ?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
    <br/>
    <br/>

    <label for="item">Cameras</label>
    <select name="item" id="rent">
        <option selected disabled>SELECT ITEM</option>
<?php foreach ($rentq as $row) : ?>
    <option value="<?= $row['item_brand']?>" data-sireal="<?= $row['s_n'] ?>"><?= $row['item_brand'] ?></option>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select><br/>
    <br/>
<input type="hidden" name="sn" id="itemsn" value="">
    <label name="from_date">RENT FROM</label>
    <input type="date" name="from_date"><br/>
    <label name="from_hour">RENT FROM Hour</label>
    <input type="time" name="from_hour"><br/>
    <label name="to_date">RENT TO</label>
    <input type="date" name="to_date"><br/>
    <label name="to_hour">RENT FROM Hour</label>
    <input type="time" name="to_hour"><br/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send Rent">
</form>

<div class="result">

</div>
```

```html
if($_POST){

 $name = $_POST['rnt_name'];
 $item = $_POST['item'];
 $fdate = $_POST['from_date'];
 $fhour = $_POST['from_hour'];
 $tdate = $_POST['to_date'];
 $thour = $_POST['to_hour'];
 $sn = $_POST['sn'];


 $csheck = "SELECT * FROM rent";
 $ckq = mysqli_query($link,$csheck);

    foreach ($ckq as $res) {}

   $count = "SELECT item_brand = '$item',s_n = '$sn',COUNT(*)
FROM item
WHERE status = 1 AND item_brand = '$item' AND s_n = '$sn'";
    $cnt = mysqli_query($link,$count);
 foreach ($cnt as $itm);

$itmq = "SELECT rent_item = '$item',COUNT(*)
FROM rent ";
$itemres = mysqli_query($link,$itmq);

foreach ($itemres as $missitm){};
```

```html
if(($fdate >= $res['rent_from_d'] && $res['rent_to_d'] >= $tdate && $missitm['COUNT(*)'] >= $itm['COUNT(*)']   ) || ($fdate > $res['rent_from_d'] && $res['rent_to_d'] > $tdate && $fdate > $res['rent_from_d'] || $fdate <= $res['rent_to_d'] && $fhour <= $res['rent_to_t'] && $missitm['COUNT(*)'] >= $itm['COUNT(*)'] ) )  {
    echo 'no good Item Rented To '.$res['renter'] ;

 }else{
     $newrent = "INSERT INTO rent (renter,rent_item,rent_from_d,rent_from_t,rent_to_d,rent_to_t) 
VALUES ('$name','$item','$fdate','$fhour','$tdate','$thour')";
     mysqli_query($link,$newrent);

    echo 'pass';

 }
```

this is what I get in my database after form submit

```
rent_id renter  rent_item   sn  rent_from_d rent_from_t rent_to_d   rent_to_t
115    dror        x70     1234 2018-11-29  10:00     2018-11-29    14:00
```

What I am trying to do is create a rent system. My problem is how to validate if items are selected between two dates and time. Every time new rent is created, the status of the specific item that has been chosen set to 0, so that the system will no longer available.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add the date formats.

Comment: Step 1. Store date and time as a single entity

Comment: can you please explain why? what is the difference between storing the date and the time separately?

Comment: Perhaps what you're looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3269434/whats-the-most-efficient-way-to-test-two-integer-ranges-for-overlap

Comment: What are these two `$res['rent_from_d'] >= $fdate`.

Comment: I have updated the post

Comment: I have managed to get this work see the update post