# Check number range exist in the another number range in php

Tags: php

I have one input number range `20 to 60`. And i have predefined number ranges as follows :

- `18 to 24`
- `25 to 34`
- `35 to 44`
- `45 to 54`
- `55 to 64`
- `65+`

I want to get the predefined number ranges which is between the input number range.
For the range `20` to `60` I would like to get `18 to 24, 25 to 34, 35 to 44, 45 to 54, 55 to 64` .

Below is the code which tried to achieve this :

```
     $min_age = 20; $max_age = 60; $age_range = [];
     if(in_array($min_age, range(18, 24)) || in_array($max_age, range(18, 24))) {
         $age_range[] = [ 'type' => AgeRangeType::AGE_RANGE_18_24 ];
     } 
     
     if(in_array($min_age, range(25, 34)) || in_array($max_age, range(25, 34))) {
         $age_range[] = [ 'type' => AgeRangeType::AGE_RANGE_25_34 ];
     }
     if(in_array($min_age, range(35, 44)) || in_array($max_age, range(35, 44))) {
         $age_range[] = [ 'type' => AgeRangeType::AGE_RANGE_35_44 ];
     }
     if(in_array($min_age, range(45, 54)) || in_array($max_age, range(45, 54))) {
         $age_range[] = [ 'type' => AgeRangeType::AGE_RANGE_45_54 ];
     }
     if(in_array($min_age, range(55, 64)) || in_array($max_age, range(55, 64))) {
         $age_range[] = [ 'type' => AgeRangeType::AGE_RANGE_55_64 ];
     }
     if(in_array($min_age, range(65, 65)) || in_array($max_age, range(65, 65))) {
         $age_range[] = [ 'type' => AgeRangeType::AGE_RANGE_65_UP ];
     }
```

But i'm not getting the proper result.

Comment: `20` is not between `25` and `34`, and neither is `60`. You need to cover the cases where your min and max completely "encompass" the predefined range, as well.

Comment: @Cbroe It could be the other way around. For `18 to 24` the section `20 to 24` lies within the range `20 to 60`. I'm not sure what is wanted here.

Comment: If you're not getting the proper result, given the code in your question, you should be very explicit about the results you do want to get. From what I can see in your question only the range `65+` needs to be discounted, because there's no overlap with the `20 to 60` range, is that correct?

Comment: It would be nice to see the definition of `AgeRangeType`.

Comment: FYI - there's a faster way to find out if two ranges overlap than generating (`range()`) an array full of numbers - [What's the most efficient way to test if two ranges overlap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3269434/whats-the-most-efficient-way-to-test-if-two-ranges-overlap)

Comment: @CBroe Yes I would like to get the predefined range which has even one number match with the input range

Comment: make one `allowed array` from 20-60 and do `array_intersect()` with the respective `age_range`. If the result is not empty it has a match. Saves a lot of `in_array()` and  `range()` creating.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware `AgeRangeType` is a Enum reference from google ads api. Which returns some id. I just wanted all the ids to be in one array

Comment: Ah, I found it: [AgeRangeType](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/reference/rpc/v7/AgeRangeTypeEnum.AgeRangeType#age_range_18_24).

Answer (score 2):

I created this function:

```
function getGoogleAgeRanges($minumumAge, $maximumAge)
{
    $ageRanges = [AgeRangeType::AGE_RANGE_18_24 => ['min' => 18, 'max' => 24],
                  AgeRangeType::AGE_RANGE_25_34 => ['min' => 25, 'max' => 34],
                  AgeRangeType::AGE_RANGE_35_44 => ['min' => 35, 'max' => 44],
                  AgeRangeType::AGE_RANGE_45_54 => ['min' => 45, 'max' => 54],
                  AgeRangeType::AGE_RANGE_55_64 => ['min' => 55, 'max' => 64],
                  AgeRangeType::AGE_RANGE_65_UP => ['min' => 65, 'max' => 135]];
   $result = [];
   foreach ($ageRanges as $googleRangeEnum => $ageRange) {
       if ($ageRange['max'] >= $minumumAge && 
           $ageRange['min'] <= $maximumAge) {
           $result[] = $googleRangeEnum;
       }
       elseif (!empty($result)) break;
   }
   return $result;
}   
          
print_r(getGoogleAgeRanges(20, 60));
```

When executed it returns all age ranges except the 65+ one. It is quite self explanatory: I created an array with data to work with, then loop through the array to gather what is needed, and return it.

Comment: If the ranges are ordered then one micro-optimization would be to return early when we find the first non matching range.

Comment: @Hendrik How about: `elseif (!empty($result)) break;`? It's, on average, probably a bit faster, but there's not much in it.

Comment: Looks good to me. Probably not especially needed here, but could be useful for general solution with lots of ordered ranges.

Answer (score 0):

Just changed a code little bit and it worked as i expected :

```
$min_age = 20;
$max_age = 60;
$age_range = [];
        
if(in_array(18, range($min_age, $max_age)) || in_array(24, range($min_age, $max_age))) {
      $age_range[] = [ 'type' => AgeRangeType::AGE_RANGE_18_24 ];
}       
if(in_array(25, range($min_age, $max_age)) || in_array(34, range($min_age, $max_age))) {
      $age_range[] = [ 'type' => AgeRangeType::AGE_RANGE_25_34 ];
}
if(in_array(35, range($min_age, $max_age)) || in_array(44, range($min_age, $max_age))) {
      $age_range[] = [ 'type' => AgeRangeType::AGE_RANGE_35_44 ];
}
if(in_array(45, range($min_age, $max_age)) || in_array(54, range($min_age, $max_age))) {
      $age_range[] = [ 'type' => AgeRangeType::AGE_RANGE_45_54 ];
}
if(in_array(55, range($min_age, $max_age)) || in_array(64, range($min_age, $max_age))) {
      $age_range[] = [ 'type' => AgeRangeType::AGE_RANGE_55_64 ];
}
if($min_age >= 65 || $max_age >= 65) {
      $age_range[] = [ 'type' => AgeRangeType::AGE_RANGE_65_UP ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Admittedly, the bones of my answer are based on KIKO's answer, but I made some PSR-12 compliant choices, some personal code styling adjustments, and adjusted the way the enum names were accessed (so that they work).  I have somewhat of a bias toward using array destructuring in a foreach loop because I like the avoidance of array syntax in the conditional expression -- I feel it just reads a little cleaner.  Because `$result` is guaranteed to exist, calling `!empty()` is unnecessary -- a truthy check will tell you if the array is non-empty.  Read [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.enumerations.basics.php) about using object property property syntax to access the enum's string value.  Because the whitelist of enum cases will not be changed, it is sensible to declare it as a constant -- which enjoys a global scope (see the alternative approach link).

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/ZjG9a)) ([An alternative approach](https://3v4l.org/1lZZk))

```
enum AgeRangeType
{
    case UNSPECIFIED;            // Not specified.
    case UNKNOWN;                // Used for return value only. Represents value unknown in this version.
    case AGE_RANGE_18_24;        // Between 18 and 24 years old.
    case AGE_RANGE_25_34;        // Between 25 and 34 years old.
    case AGE_RANGE_35_44;        // Between 35 and 44 years old.
    case AGE_RANGE_45_54;        // Between 45 and 54 years old.
    case AGE_RANGE_55_64;        // Between 55 and 64 years old.
    case AGE_RANGE_65_UP;        // 65 years old and beyond.
    case AGE_RANGE_UNDETERMINED; // Undetermined age range.
}

$ageRanges = [
    AgeRangeType::AGE_RANGE_18_24->name => ['min' => 18, 'max' => 24],
    AgeRangeType::AGE_RANGE_25_34->name => ['min' => 25, 'max' => 34],
    AgeRangeType::AGE_RANGE_35_44->name => ['min' => 35, 'max' => 44],
    AgeRangeType::AGE_RANGE_45_54->name => ['min' => 45, 'max' => 54],
    AgeRangeType::AGE_RANGE_55_64->name => ['min' => 55, 'max' => 64],
    AgeRangeType::AGE_RANGE_65_UP->name => ['min' => 65, 'max' => 135]
];

$min_age = 20;
$max_age = 60;

$result = [];
foreach ($ageRanges as $enum => ['min' => $min, 'max' => $max]) {
   if ($max >= $min_age && $min <= $max_age) {
       $result[] = $enum;
   } elseif ($result) {
       break;
   }
}

var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'AGE_RANGE_18_24',
  1 => 'AGE_RANGE_25_34',
  2 => 'AGE_RANGE_35_44',
  3 => 'AGE_RANGE_45_54',
  4 => 'AGE_RANGE_55_64',
)
```