# How to check if one of multiple numbers is between 2 other numbers

Tags: javascript

For example, if I want to check if any number between 6 and 9 is between 8 and 16, how would I do this? In this case it would be true because 8 and 9 are both between 8 and 16.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function rangeOverlaps(rangeA, rangeB) {
    return rangeA[0]<=rangeB[1] && rangeB[0]<=rangeA[1]
}
console.log(rangeOverlaps([8,16],[6,9])) //true
console.log(rangeOverlaps([8,16],[8,8])) //true
console.log(rangeOverlaps([8,16],[4,7])) //false
```

Explanation: [What's the most efficient way to test if two ranges overlap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3269434/whats-the-most-efficient-way-to-test-if-two-ranges-overlap)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
    function trying(x,y,z,w){
    return ((x >= z && x <= w) && (y >= z 
    && y <= w));
    }
```